# Android setMinimumLatency not working API 23

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I have this code below but it seems that the jobService never gets trigger not even after 5sec. In later versions this works fine.

```
            JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MyJob.class);

            JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
                    .setMinimumLatency(5000)
                    .setPersisted(true).build();

            jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

Comment: I don't think you can set a minimum latency that low. Its going to translate this into an AlarmManager call, and the minimum latency for that (assuming the phone is on and not dozing) is 20s.

Comment: @GabeSechan In later versions of android this works. Can you explain me with simple examples how  setMinimumLatency and setOverrideDeadline works in different apis because in docs isnt clarified well?